# simple jquery css aminated fade

Tags: jquery, animation, fade

I have searched the net but I can't seem to find a solution that fits my example. 
I want all other divs to fade out when one div is hovered over. I have this working but how do I make it animate so that the fade lasts 0.5 seconds?
JSfiddle below
Many thanks

```
$(function() {
    $(".box").hover(function() {
        $(this).css('opacity', '1').siblings(".box").css('opacity', '0.5')
    });
    $(".OuterBox").mouseout(function() {
        $(this).find(".box").css('opacity', '1')
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JE5fe/

Answer (score 0):

Try this on:

http://jsfiddle.net/JE5fe/6/

```
$(this).css('opacity', '1').siblings(".box").css('opacity', '0');
```

Comment: that is that same as what I already had. I want it to animate gradually over 0.5 seconds. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".box").mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).animate({
        opacity: 1
    }, 500).siblings(".box").stop().animate({
        opacity: 0.5
    }, 500);    
}).mouseout(function () {
    $(".box").stop().animate({
        opacity: 1
    }, 500);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JE5fe/15/

Don't forget to check if its correct ;)

Answer (score 0):

Make the animation is more naturally.

http://jsfiddle.net/fcPhL/

```
$(function() {
    $('.OuterBox').on({
        mouseenter: function () {
            $(this).stop().css('opacity', 1).siblings().stop().fadeTo(500, 0.5);
        },
        mouseleave: function (e) {
            if (!$(e.relatedTarget).hasClass('box')) {
                $(this).siblings().fadeTo(500, 1);
            }
        }
    }, '.box');
});
```